# Cv2 all Facial features detection

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I have a program that detects the eyes, mouth, nose and face but it is very inaccurate.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('face.xml')
mouth_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('mouth.xml')
nose_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('nose.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('eye.xml')


image = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayImage, minNeighbors=5)
mouth = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayImage, minNeighbors=5)
nose = nose_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayImage, minNeighbors=5)
eye = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayImage, minNeighbors=5)

print(type(face))

if len(face) == 0:
    print("No faces found")

else:
    print("mouth")
    print(mouth)
    print(mouth.shape)
    print("Number of mouths detected: " + str(mouth.shape[0]))

    print("Face")
    print(face)
    print(face.shape)
    print("Number of faces detected: " + str(face.shape[0]))

    print("nose")
    print(nose)
    print(nose.shape)
    print("Number of noses detected: " + str(nose.shape[0]))

    print("eye")
    print(eye)
    print(eye.shape)
    print("Number of eye detected: " + str(eye.shape[0]))

    for (x,y,w,h) in face:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)

    for (x,y,w,h) in mouth:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),1)

    for (x,y,w,h) in nose:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),1)

    for (x,y,w,h) in eye:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),1)


cv2.imshow('Image with faces',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expect it to look like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCIvW.png)

The actual result is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv4SV.png)

I also would like it to show the ears and hair.
Also can this be preferably without dlib as I am unable to use it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code as starting point. You will have to tune parameters to get better results.

```
image = cv2.imread("sample_face.jpeg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, minNeighbors=5)

if len(face) == 0:
    print("No faces found")

else:

    for (x,y,w,h) in face:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        eye = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 
                                           minSize=(80, 30),
                                           minNeighbors=5)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eye:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(255,255,0),2)


        nose = nose_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 
                                             scaleFactor=4.9, 
                                             minNeighbors=4, 
                                             flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

        for (nx,ny,nw,nh) in nose:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(nx,ny),(nx+nw,ny+nh),(255,255,255),2)

        mouth = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 
                                               scaleFactor=1.1, 
                                               maxSize=(100,150))
        for (mx,my,mw,mh) in mouth:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(mx,my),(mx+mw,my+mh),(255,0,0),2)
```

Also, go through [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html#gsc.tab=0) tutorial on how to do face detection using `Haar Feature-based Cascade Classifiers`.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV now provides a FaceMark API. You can use it for getting a more accurate representation of the facial landmarks which are required by your application. This is not a solution for getting the points for ears and hairs though.

I guess you will have to label the data yourself and retrain the facemark model or work with classic image processing with the extracted chin points.

Hope this helps.

Here is the link: [OpenCV FaceMark API](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dec/tutorial_facemark_usage.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the link isn't for python, I think its for javaScript.